# Connection timed out: connect for Eclipse JAX-RS program

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jsp

I am learning `JAX-RS` web-services and trying to implement a simple web-application based on the example given in book - [java web services up and running 2nd edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920029571.do).

I have a `HTML` page that makes an `AJAX` call to `JSP` using `JQuery`. This `JSP` takes the help back-end `Java Class` to display data to the user. The `Java Class` is a JAX-RS client that calls an `XML` file present at `http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml`.

Here is my HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JSON</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" 
        src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
      $.getJSON('http://localhost:8081/rest/getCDs.jsp', function(response) {
         var cds = response.catalog.cd; 
         alert(JSON.stringify(cds));
         $.each(cds, function(ind, val) { 
             $('#container').append('<li>' + cds[ind].title + ': ' + 
                                         cds[ind].artist + '</li>'); } );

      });
    </script>  
</head>
  <body>
    <ul id = 'container'></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

My `JSP` file `getCDs.jsp`:

```
<%@ page import="cds.FetchXML"%>

<jsp:useBean id="fetcher" type="cds.FetchXML" class="cds.FetchXML">
</jsp:useBean>
<jsp:getProperty name="fetcher" property="json" />
```

My `Java` class:

```
package cds;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class FetchXML {
    public String getJson() {
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            // Fetch the XML document from the W3C site.
            String xml = "";
            URL url = new URL("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                    conn.setConnectTimeout(180000); // 3minutes
                    conn.setReadTimeout(180000);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));

        // Read the document records.
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            xml += line;
        in.close();

        // Clean up the XML.
        xml = xml.replace("'", "");
        System.out.println("xml--" + xml);
        // Transform the XML document into a JSON object,
        // in this case an array of song objects.
        json = XML.toJSONObject(xml.toLowerCase());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Got an exception...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json.toString(); // JSON document
}
```

}

When I deploy this web-application on tomcat and try to access the `HTML` page then I am getting below exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Also I observed that the connection timeout for reading and getting the connection to `3 minutes`, the application is not waiting till that time.

Please let me know where I am doing mistake this in this basic example?

Comment: What's the full stack trace? Try to debug it from within Eclipse and use the J! button on the Breakpoints view to break on ConnectExceptions.

Comment: Now I ran the program once again, it worked without issues. But I am not clear on why I was not able to get results earlier. I was able to access the URL for cd_catalog.xml even earlier also.